# what does the particle ~하고 means?

Tags: particle

I was trying to translate IU’s song entitled “Love Poem” then, I encountered the word “기도하고”. I know that “기도” means prayer but what does it mean if you put the particle “하고”?

Comment: -하다 is a suffix used to make nouns into verbs and adjectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lyric of that song, '누군가 기도하고 있나 봐' (I think someone is praying)

'기도하고' is 'praying' in English and it is not independent word here.

기도하고 + 있다 = 'be praying'

ex) 엄마가 노래**하고** 있다 mom is singing
나는 공부**하고** 있다 I am studying